# How to return args of a subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I'm running a bash script which consist of many other commands within the python

mybash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=10
echo variable is equal to $var
```

and inside the python while running `.sh`

```
if echo variable is equal to $var == echo variable is equal to 10:
print ('variable is 10')
```

and I try to do it by:

`process = Popen('sh mybash.sh', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)`

I'm try to get the args value of each commands inside the bash script, but `process.args` just return `sh mybash.sh`. how can I return the args value of each commands inside the script line by line while it executed?

Comment: What do you mean args? arguments are what you put into a function / script. If you want to take something out you'll have to `echo` each argument in the `.sh` script and read stdout.

Comment: is it necessary to wrap this bash script in a python script? you could just use one or the other and then debug it.

Comment: You don't need `shell=True` here; `Popen(['sh', 'mybash.sh'], ...)`

Comment: `mybash.sh` is effectively a black box; you can't get any information about what is happening inside it short of parsing the file yourself.

Comment: actually, I want to filter some commands inside the bash script on runtime. so, that's why first I'm running the bash script inside the python to control those commands!

Comment: @chepner how can run the `mynahs.sh` and then filter some commands runtime?

Comment: You need to write a new script; you can't just pick and choose which commands to run.

Comment: and in new script how can I control the main script runtime? I just need to see the executed command lines like `echo variable is equal to 10` runtime!

Answer (score 1):

You are not running bash script inside of python. You are running bash interpreter (sh) which runs mybash.sh script. You can not access individual bash commands from python, but you can use -x flag.

```
process = Popen('sh -x mybash.sh', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
```

Comment: Because of `shell=True`, this actually runs `sh -c 'sh -x mybash.sh'`

Comment: actually, the goal is filtering commands inside the `mynahs.sh` runtime, not just running the bash! is there any command, let me to access those command of the bash script runtime and line by line?